# Call a function in parfor loop in matlab

Tags: matlab, parfor

```
   parfor i=1:10
   k1=0.30+(0.35/20)*i
   AX(i)=k1;
   for j=1:10
      k2=0.5+(.35/20)*j
       AY(i,j)=k2;
     wph(i,j)=wph1(k1,k2)
     end 
     end
```

where wph1(k1,k2) is a self defined function to calculate the phonon energy. But while i tried to run this code i eneded up with an error:

> Error: An UndefinedFunction error was thrown on the workers for 'wph'. 
>   This might be because the file containing 'wph' is not accessible on
>   the workers.  Use addAttachedFiles(pool, files) to specify the
>   required files to be attached.  See the documentation for
>   'parallel.Pool/addAttachedFiles' for more details.
>
> Error in yorraman (line 7) parfor i=1:10
>
> Caused by:
>       Undefined function 'wph' for input arguments of type 'double'."

How to fix this? please help.

Comment: I have a concern about k2 value. k2 is index and its value should be an integer without decimal value

Comment: k2 is not an index. it is a variable. I have defined my function like this: 
function u= wph1(k1,k2)
p=3.1415926535;
u = 2*cos(2*p*k1) + 2*cos(2*p*k2) + 2*cos(2*p*(k1 - k2));
end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just got small bug instead of `pk1` and `pk2` write `p*k1` and `p*k2`.
Moreover, in matlab you have `pi` already defined so your code should be

```
tic
parfor i=1:10
    k1=0.30+(0.35/20)*i
    AX(i)=k1;
    for j=1:10
        k2=0.5+(.35/20)*j
        AY(i,j)=k2;
        wph(i,j)=wph1(k1,k2);
    end
end
toc

function u = wph1(k1,k2) 
    u = 2*cos(2*pi*k1) + 2*cos(2*pi*k2) + 2*cos(2*pi*(k1 - k2)); 
end
```

Other important note, for this case use 'for' and not 'parfor', unless every function call take more than half second to run, otherwise your code will run slower, just the setup and call to parfor takes like 10-50ms.

And now for the magic. In matlab you dont need for loops at all for this sort of calculation, so the fastest code is:

```
tic
i=1:10; k1=0.30+(0.35/20)*i; AX=k1;
j=1:10; k2=0.50+(0.35/20)*j'; AY=k2;
wph=wph1(k1,k2);
toc
% bonus: plot
[X,Y] = meshgrid(AX,AY);
surf(X,Y,wph)

function u = wph1(k1,k2) 
    u = 2*cos(2*pi*k1) + 2*cos(2*pi*k2) + 2*cos(2*pi*(k1 - k2)); 
end
```

Comment: I need to create (let's say) 10 k2 values for 1 k1 value that is why I was using the loop. I corrected those mistakes in my program still i got the same error. One more thing, is it applicable for calling more than one function? I need to call more than one local functions in my main program and in every cases i ended up with the same error.

Comment: You still don't need for loop. and for your error i told you that you have bug. look at my answer.